# FadeIn animation not working when loading through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I'm using the load() function to load code to my jsp page. When i'm loading code to my page it works but i would like so it would do so with a fadeIn animation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#connectBtn").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        data: { connected: "connected" },
        url: "Servlet",
        success: function() {
            $("#content").load("connected.jsp", function() {
                
                $.getScript("js/jquery.js");
                $.getScript("js/connected.js");
                
                //this part here doesn't work
                $(this).fadeIn("slow");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Try `$('#content').fadeOut(0).fadeIn("slow");`  instead of `$(this).fadeIn("slow");` .. I don't think `$(this)` will catch the `$("#content")` element .. anyway after trying my solution change `$("#content")` to `$(this)` and see .. 2nd: `fadeIn()` works for the invisible elements .. logically how can it `fadeIn` while its visible already

Comment: $(this) actually does catch the element.